# Return statement is not working properly in Java

Tags: java, null, return

I have the following Code

```
static String super_reduced_string(StringBuilder s){
   for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){
       if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)){
           StringBuilder s1= s.delete(i,i+2);
           //System.out.println("Reduced String is "+s1 +s1.length());
           if(s1.length()==0){
               System.out.println("Reduced String is"+s1 +s1.length());
               return "Empty String";

               }
           super_reduced_string(s1);
       }
   }
    return s.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = in.next();
    String result = super_reduced_string(new StringBuilder(s));
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

When I pass input as "aa" its returning "Empty String" as Output but when I pass "baab" ,Its returning null as the output. I can't understand why it is happening like that.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You have it setup to delete duplicate letters:

```
if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)){
           StringBuilder s1= s.delete(i,i+2);
```

thus when you pass `aa` to the method, it will delete both letters because they are the same. If you pass `baab`, than it will delete `aa` leaving you with `bb`, then it will delete `bb` because they are also duplicates.

**EDIT:**

You need to add a `return` statement  that will execute if your `if` does not:

```
static String super_reduced_string(StringBuilder s){
       for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){
           if(s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(i+1)){
               StringBuilder s1= s.delete(i,i+2);
               //System.out.println("Reduced String is "+s1 +s1.length());
               if(s1.length()==0){
                   System.out.println("Reduced String is"+s1 +s1.length());
                   return "Empty String";

                   }

               /*
                * Needs a return statement, otherwise it will return the
                * empty value below
                */
               return super_reduced_string(s1);
           }
       }
        return s.toString(); 
        /*
         * If the if statement does not execute,
         * and the statement above is missing a
         * return declaration, then this will return
         * an empty string: ""
         */
    }
```

Comment: Yes,and In that case also it should return "Empty String" right?,But it is not returning "Empty String"

Comment: When I debugged the code it entered the if(s1.length()==0) loop,printed the syso statement but it did not return "Empty String".

Comment: @Ravi index starts at zero, so you should check `if(s1.length() == -1){}`

Comment: It did not work when I changed the code to if(s1.length() == -1){}

Comment: Could you please try to run the above program in your eclipse.

Comment: Forget about the -1 check I gave you, try this instead `if(s1.length == 0 || s1 == null){}`. I would test it In eclipse but I have been away from my computer for an extended time and I'm stuck using mobile.

Comment: You might want to rethink what you've written here: `if(s1.length() == 0 || s1 == null)`. Does that really make sense?

Comment: Ohh! I was thinking about the wrong part of the question and the code! I have to thank Tom for making me think outside the box. Thanks Tom! ;) updated my answer with a working solution.